# How can I join two strings in go templates?

Tags: string, go-templates

I found this documentation to [join two strings](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join), but this doesn't work inside go templates.

Is there a way to join strings inside a go template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a function to join the strings and add it to the template [func map](https://godoc.org/text/template#Template.Funcs):

```
func join(sep string, s ...string) string {
    return strings.Join(s, sep)
}
```

Add the function to template before parsing:

```
t, err := template.New(name).Funcs(template.FuncMap{"join": join}).Parse(text)
```

Use it in the template like this:

```
{{$x := join ", " "hello" "world"}}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/jNxRyxPhAWo)

I assign to variable `$x` to show how use the function result in a template expression. The result can be used directly as an argument to another function without assigning to a variable.

Here's a version of the function that works with slices instead of variadic arguments:

```
func join(sep string, s []string) string {
    return strings.Join(s, sep)
}
```

Use it like this where `.` is a slice:

```
{{$x := join ", " .}}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/MTXDnl3f_Xu).

If your goal is to join two strings directly do the output, then then use `{{a}}sep{{b}}` where `a` and `b` are the strings and `sep` is the separator.

Use range to join a slice to the output. Here's an example that joins slice `.` with separator `", "`.:

```
{{range $i, $v := .}}{{if $i}}, {{end}}{{$v}}{{end}}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/jyshg22JQ_-).

Answer (score 6):

Use a combination of `delimit` and `slice`, e.g.

```
{{ delimit (slice "foo" "bar" "buzz") ", " }}
<!-- returns the string "foo, bar, buzz" -->
```

Originally from the [gohugo docs](https://gohugo.io/templates/functions/)

Comment: `delimit` is not part of the default [template functions](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Functions)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I joined two strings in go template language (this is within a Helm template for Kubernetes).  In this case I am creating a host name using go's `printf` function:

```
host: {{ printf "%v%v" "my-super" ".apps.my.org" }}
```

Put in a `%v` for each value.

The output is:

```
host: my-super.apps.my.org
```

You can put spaces between the `%v` values, or commas, or whatever -- check with go's string format options for more, um, options!

Comment: +1 Yet and again, if you want an SO answer that makes sense, keep scrolling down, and down, and down... :D

Answer (score 1):

In the template example https://golang.org/src/text/template/example_test.go they show you how to do this.

In summary:

```
var funcs = template.FuncMap{"join": strings.Join}
...
masterTmpl, err := template.New("master").Funcs(funcs).Parse(master)
```

There's some other neat tricks in the example too.