# How to concatenate a variable and a string with the go templates

Tags: go, go-templates

I need to concatenate a scoped variable and a string with go templates, something like that:

```
{{ $url := .Release.Namespace + ".myurl.com" }}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39023060/13860

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you're coming from the Helm world due to `.Release.Namespace` and may not want the Go portion of this.

## For Helm people:

Everything inside of the `{{}}` will be removed after Helm processes your YAML. To achieve a locally scoped variable, you can use two `{{}}` values.

The first is `{{ $url := print .Release.Namespace ".myurl.com" }}`. It won't produce anything after Helm processes your YAML, but it will assign the local variable `$url` to the value of `.Release.Namespace` and the constant `.myurl.com`.

The next is `{{ $url }}`, which will allow you to use the value stored in the `$url` variable.

Bringing it together `{{ $url := print .Release.Namespace ".myurl.com" }}{{ $url }}` will produce `subdomain.myurl.com` should the value of `.Release.Namespace` be `subdomain`.

## For Go developers:

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/4fAbstm82dJ)

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

const (
    // exampleTemplate is a template for a StackOverflow example.
    exampleTemplate = `{{ $url := print .Release.Namespace ".myurl.com" }}{{ $url }}`
)

// templateData is the data structure to pass to the template.
type templateData struct {
    Release Release
}

// Release is a fake Go data structure for this example.
type Release struct {
    Namespace string
}

func main() {
    // Create the template.
    tmpl := template.Must(template.New("example").Parse(exampleTemplate))

    // Create the data to put into the template.
    data := templateData{Release: Release{Namespace: "subdomain"}}

    // Execute the template.
    if err := tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, data); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to execute template.\nError: %s", err.Error())
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP is asking for. If they just wanted to output `subdomain.myurl.com`, they could just use `{{ .Release.Namespace}}.myurl.com`. I assume they want the computed value stored in `$url` for later reuse in the template.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that lol. Made some quick edits.

Answer (score 3):

To simply concatenate values in templates, you may use the builtin `print` function.

See this example:

```
const src = `{{ $url := print .Something ".myurl.com" }}Result: {{ $url }}`
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(src))

params := map[string]interface{}{
    "Something": "test",
}

if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, params); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8jzyoQdRfb0)):

```
Result: test.myurl.com
```

It of course works if your values are not `string`s because `print` is an alias for [`fmt.Sprint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprint):

```
params := map[string]interface{}{
    "Something": 23,
}
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Zd6BwiaUMPl)):

```
Result: 23.myurl.com
```