# Concatenation in Helm go script

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

```
{{- with .Values.environment.staging }}
    value: {{ .baseUrl }}
{{- end }}
```

I want to set the environment value `staging` dynamically based on the key value pair stored in `podAnnotations`.

```
{{- $envValue := .Values.podAnnotations.environment }}
```

The above two expressions work independently but not when combined as following:

```
{{- with .Values.environment "." $envValue }}
    value: {{ .baseUrl }}
{{- end }}
```

I'm not exactly sure how to concatenate a local variable within the `with` statement in `helm`. Solution to fix the problem or any links to documentation would be useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41614235/13860

Comment: I'm not an expert in go templating but the link you have suggested returns a string. Whereas in my case in need to access the values object (or map i guess).

Comment: Maybe this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26152088/13860

Comment: @Flimzy That's exactly what i've been looking for. Thanks a ton!!! :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access a map value using a variable key in a Go template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152088/access-a-map-value-using-a-variable-key-in-a-go-template)